# setInterval not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I'm trying to get it so the confirm window pops up every n seconds that the user inputs into the prompt but the confirm window pops up immediately regardless of the input.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is what my button looks like:

```
<button onclick="timer_prompt()">FUN</button>
```

---

my simple functions:

```
function timer_prompt()
{
    var seconds = prompt("Enter Time Interval In Seconds Please");
    seconds = seconds*1000;
    if(seconds>0)
    {
     setInterval(confirm_timer(), seconds);
    }
        else
        {
        alert("You entered invalid content");
        }

} 


function confirm_timer()
{
    confirm("YOU HAVE SET A TIMER!!!");
}
```

Comment: you should pass a function reference instead of executing it

Answer (score 6):

You are calling, not assigning

```
setInterval(confirm_timer(), seconds);
```

needs to be

```
setInterval(confirm_timer, seconds);
```

Comment: I would say "You are calling, not *referencing*"

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work.  The confirm window wouldn't pop up at all after inputting a value.

Answer (score 1):

setInterval takes a function as its first argument, you are passing the return value of the function. Remove the parentheses from confirm_timer in the setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this way?

```js
function timer_prompt() {
    var seconds = prompt("Enter time interval in seconds please.");
    seconds = seconds * 1000;

    if(seconds > 0) {
        callInterval(seconds);
    } else {
        alert("You entered invalid content");
    }
}


function callInterval(seconds) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        confirm("You have set a timer!");
        callInterval(seconds);
    }, seconds);
}

timer_prompt();
```